# how do I make the bullet move Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a very simpel flash game to understand AS3. I have made a cirkel with controls. When I press the space I want to fire a bullet. I have tried for, while loops and different tutorials but I just can't figure out how to do this.
This is m code:

```
import flash.net.drm.LoadVoucherSetting;

//controls 
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);
var dir:String = "default";

function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
{
    ball_mc.x -=  10;
    dir = "venstre";
}
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
    ball_mc.x +=  10;
    dir = "hojre";
}
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
{
    ball_mc.y -=  10;
    dir = "op";
}
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
{
    ball_mc.y +=  10;
    dir = "ned";
}
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
{
    shootBullet();
}
}

var speed1:int = 1;
function shootBullet():void
{
//instantiate your object
var bullet:Bullets = new Bullets  ;

//add it to the stage
addChild(bullet);

//object will default to x=0 , y=0 so you can define that as well
bullet.x = ball_mc.x;
bullet.y = ball_mc.y +(ball_mc.width/2);

bullet.y += 10 * 2;

}

stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it move you need to use some event that happens repeatedly with some interval.
A [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html):

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(25);//interval, milliseconds
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

var speedX:int = 0;
var speedY:int = 1;
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    bullet.y += speedX;
    bullet.x += speedY;
}
```

Or an [`ENTER_FRAME`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:enterFrame) event:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
function onFrame(event:Event):void {
    bullet.y += speedX;
    bullet.x += speedY;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling that I needed something that ran repeatedly. but how do you incorporate that in my code. I have tried the above timer code, but it doesnt work because the bullet is first created when pressing space:

Comment: @JohnDinh, you may declare `var bullet:Bullets` outside the `shootBullet` function and check `if(bullet)` before adding speed to avoid `Error # 1009 (Null object reference)` in the event handler. The other option is to move this code into the `Bullets` class and let it handle its coords

Comment: Anyway, if @www0z0k is right, this isn't a good idea to store speedX and speedY on  a single variable (on Stage).
If you shoot more than one bullet, all the bullets will have the same speedX and speedY values.
As he said "The other option is to move this code into the Bullets class and let it handle its coords" AND  speedX and speedY values since it extends MovieClip.
You may consider TimerEvent as well but if you have a low fps, don't forget to add the timerEvent.updateAfterEvent method!